# Does Java have regular-old functions?

Tags: java

What I mean is, does Java have functions that exist outside of classes that I can declare? (Like, before the main class)
This is something I can do in C++ and JS, etc.

Comment: [Why Java does not allow function definitions to be present outside of the class?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/185109/why-java-does-not-allow-function-definitions-to-be-present-outside-of-the-class)

Answer (score 1):

## Static method

Declaring a [method to be `static`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) makes it non-object-oriented. Its scope is outside that of any instances of that class. Invoked via the class name, `Person.doSomething` rather than by an instance.

Often called a "[class method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)#Class_methods)" though that seems like something of a misnomer to my mind. That name suggests object-orientation where it does not exist. Java simply has no other place to store "just a function", so such functions are bolted onto a class. I think of them as orphaned code with no where else to live. Some folks consider this arrangement to be a poor design choice in Java, where an explicit holder of non-object-oriented code would have been better.

You can think of class methods as "just a function" since it is not behavior on an object.

## Lambda

Java 8 and later supports [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), where you pass a chunk of executable in the same way we pass data. This is known as [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming), distinct from [object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

This is something like "just a function" but its scope includes elements inside its defining class.